# DotNetNuke retrieve tabmodulesettings

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have a tabmoduleID. Let's say 41, in this case. I used to be able to do this to return all the tabmodulesettings for that tabmoduleid:

```
Hashtable Settings2 = ModuleController.GetTabModuleSettings(41);
```

However, GetTabModuleSettings is now obsolete and I'm supposed to "use the TabModuleSettings property of the ModuleInfo object".

All I have is tabmoduleid. I don't have the moduleid or the tabid.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
var mc = new ModuleController();
var mi = mc.GetTabModule(41);
var tSettings = mi.TabModuleSettings;
var sValue = tSettings["SettingName"];
```

-Chris

Comment: I think it will!